# Filtering using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a telephone number (string) which is "98574524521322". I need to know which country this telephone number belongs to by looking at the country code.

I have 2 tables which are `TelephoneMerchant` and `TelephoneCode`.
Note: One telephone merchant can have multiple Telephone Codes.
Note: The first 2 or 4 digits in the telephone number is the telephone `Code`, found in the `TelephoneCodes` table.

Question: I want to write a LINQ query to check who the `telephone merchant` is for the telephone number "98574524521322" ?
My workings:

```
_dbContext.TelephoneCodes.Where(c => c.Code.ToString().StartsWith("")).FirstOrDefault(c=> c.MerchantName);
```

The above query doesn't work as I am not sure how to use `StartsWith` (Or if `StartsWith` is the right method to use).

The files are given below. Can someone help me how to resolve this ?

```
public class TelephoneCode: Entity
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int TelephoneMerchantId { get; set; }

    public TelephoneMerchant? TelephoneMerchant{ get; set; }

}


public class TelephoneMerchant: Entity
{
    public string? MerchantName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TelephoneCode> TelephoneCodes { get; set; }
}
```

How the tables look like

```
Id TelephoneMerchant   MerchantName 
===================================
1   ABC                ABCMErchant
2   BBB                BBB MErcrchat

Id   Code    TelephoneMerchantId 
==================================
1    10       1
2    98       1
3    1023     2
```

Comment: How is the telephone number related to the TelephoneCode?

Comment: The first 2 or 4 digits is the `Code` found in the `TelephoneCode` table.

Comment: Why you store it as an int and not as string?

Comment: That's a good question. However, I am converting the `int` to string using `ToString()`. But then it should ideally be `string`

Comment: Does `dbContext.TelephoneCodes.Where(c => "98574524521322".StartsWith(c.Code.ToString())).FirstOrDefault(c=> c.TelephoneMerchant.MerchantName);` translate?

Comment: @illep: Yes, it should. You would also be more flexible in case in future there is a code like `+46 55`

Comment: Hopefully you normalize the incoming phone numbers and ensure that there are no whitespaces and the prefix for international numbers (e.g. `+` or `00`) is removed, otherwise you get wrong matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
string phoneNumber = "98574524521322";
IEnumerable<string> matchingMerchants = _dbContext.TelephoneCodes
    .Where(c => phoneNumber.StartsWith(c.Code.ToString()))
    .Select(c=> c.TelephoneMerchant?.MerchantName)
    .ToList();
```

Now you have all in a list.
If you really just want a single, you can also use:

```
string matchingMerchant = _dbContext.TelephoneCodes
    .FirstOrDefault(c => phoneNumber.StartsWith(c.Code.ToString())?.TelephoneMerchant?.MerchantName;
```

But i would really save `Code` in a `String`.

Comment: I am getting an error near `Select` . it says bool does not contain a definition for Select and no accessible extention method Select accepts a first arguiment of type bool

Comment: In case of ``10234524521322`` it has two different country code ``10`` and ``1023``.

Comment: @Illep, I fixed the issue closing bracket was missing, now you won't get the error

Comment: FYI, `?.` null propagating operator is still not allowed by compiler for lambda Expression

Comment: No, you do not need that EF handles nullability automatically. It will not throw exception.

Comment: I am not sure why but `?.TelephoneMerchant?.MerchantName;` part becomes Null.

Comment: I think it was an error on my end. Your solution works fine. Thank you.